# JSON parsing service

Tags: swift, ios

I created the following service for the purpose of sending in a file for parsing. I'm using the generics so that when I call `parse()` I can pass a custom type conforming to `Codable`. I'm not a huge fan of the repetition of `do {} catch {}` but I don't see any other way to avoid this.

```
import Foundation

enum JSONError: Error {
    case read,
         parse
}

struct JSONService {
    let fileName: String
    
    func parse<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        do {
            let fileContents = try self.getJsonContents()
            return try self.parseJson(data: fileContents, type: T.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func getJsonContents() throws -> Data {
        if let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.fileName, ofType: "json") {
            if let data = try String(contentsOfFile: file).data(using: .utf8) {
                return data
            }
        }
        
        throw JSONError.read
    }
    
    private func parseJson<T: Decodable>(data: Data, type: T.Type) throws -> T {
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw JSONError.parse
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method reads an object from a JSON file which is embedded in the application bundle, and aborts with a runtime error if that fails for any reason. That is fine: Bad embedded data are a *programming error* and should be detected early.

The return type of the `parse()` method should not be an optional because it never returns `nil`.

The custom error type is used to pass errors from the helper methods to the main method. That has two disadvantages:

- It hides (possible more informative) errors thrown from other methods, e.g. the JSON decoder method.
- The messages printed with `fatalError()` show only the error type and an integer, for example

  ```
  Fatal error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyApp.JSONError error 0.)
  ```

The second issue can be improved (see for example [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415) on Stack OverFlow) but I would go another route and pass on existing errors instead, where possible:

In `parseJson()` you can pass the error which the JSON decoder already throws, instead of shadowing it by a custom error:

```
private func parseJson<T: Decodable>(data: Data, type: T.Type) throws -> T {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
}
```

And in `getJsonContents()` you can use the (throwing) `Data(contentsOf: url)` method to read the data, that is also simpler than reading into a string and then converting the string to data.

It remains to handle an error in `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)`, that method does not throw an error but returns an optional.

Without the do-catching in the helper methods everything fits neatly into the main method:

```
func parse<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.fileName, withExtension: "json") else {
        fatalError("file not found")
    }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

You many also want to print the full `error` and not its `localizedDescription` because that can provide more information (and the string is not presented to the user of your program but only for diagnostic purposes).

Finally, I wonder if `fileName` should really be an instance variable. If it is only used in the `parse()` method and nowhere else then you can make it a parameter of a *static*  method:

```
struct JSONService {
    static func parse<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type, from fileName: String) -> T {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") else {
            fatalError("file not found")
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(type.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

which would be called as

```
let value = JSONService.parse(type: MyType.self, from: "filename")
```

Embedding it into a `struct JSONService` is still useful as it provides a “name space“ for its static methods. If there are only static methods then you can embed them in an `enum JSONService` instead, because no instance of that type needs to be created (thanks to @Shadowrun for reminding me about that).

Comment: If a struct has only static methods, you could argue that it shouldn't be possible to instantiate such a struct with let foo = JSONService().  One way to prevent that is to make it an enum with no cases and only static methods. Another idea would be to avoid having a type at all, which means you also don't need to worry about naming it FooService/FooHelper/FooSomething.  By making an extension on Decodable:

extension Decodable {
    init(from fileName: String)  {
...
             self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
...

Comment: @Shadowrun: You are completely right, an enum is sufficient and perhaps preferable if you only want a namespace (this was also discussed on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38585344/1187415).

Comment: @Shadowrun: Defining your own type or extending an existing type both have advantages. The advantage of your own type/namespace is that you cannot have conflicts with definitions in other modules or with future extensions of the exiting type.